# SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF in React Native

Tags: javascript, json, api, react-native

I'm trying to display data in my details page. When I click the view button in index screen. It will direct to detail page screen. So, i click the view button I facing this `[SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF]` problem.

My API Code:

```
 //get data from api
    _loadInitialState = async () => {

        const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
        const myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('language_type');
        _onSetLanguage(myArray)

        var loadAll = this.props.navigation.getParam('loadAll');
        if (loadAll == true) { this.setState({ isLoading: true }) }

        var have_access = this.props.navigation.getParam('have_access');
        if (have_access != undefined) { this.setState({ have_access: have_access }) }
        if (staticData.get_centre_settings() != null) { this.setState({ have_access: true }) }

        let today = Moment();
        this.setState({
            today: Moment(today).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        })

        this.setState({ token: token });
        var staff_id = this.props.navigation.getParam('id');
        this.setState({ staff_id: staff_id });


        fetch(FetchURL.get_baseURL() +  "leave/" + staff_id , {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ token,

            }
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
             alert(json)
            if (json.error) {
                alert(json.error);
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    staffLeave: json,
                    isLoading: false
                });


            }

        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
            alert(err)
            // alert(strings.data_fail);
        })
    this.setState({ view_access: true })


    }
```

I think the API is working correctly because i test the API in POSTMAN. My data was display.

Comment: Check the network section in your browser's developer tools. Post the *exact* response body from the server.

Comment: What u mean by ``exact response body from the server`` this

Comment: The response body is the content that the server route `FetchURL.get_baseURL() +  "leave/" + staff_id` sends back to the client.